# A question regarding the notions of left-right differentiability

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f:[a,b]  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. We can then say it is *continuous* at the points $a,b$ with unequivocality; we don't concern ourselves with right or left continuity. This follows immediately from the definition of continuity, since per the definition of continuity at some point $c$ we only consider $x$ values *within the domain* of $f$ which satisfy $|x-c|<\delta$; hence, if it is right-continuous at $a$ it is necessarily continuous at $a$.

When discussing continuity, I'm pretty sure you merely concern yourself with points within the domain of the function being considered, which is why, for example, $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continuous at $x=0$ rather than the weaker right-continuous.

Can this logic be applied to derivatives? Let $f:[a,b]  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Let us suppose the right-derivative exists at $a$. Define $g(h) = \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}$. Note that $g$ is only defined for $h>0$.

The right derivative exists, so $\lim_{h^{+}\rightarrow 0} g(h)$ exists. But, since $g$ is only defined for $h>0$, doesn't this imply $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} g(h)$  (ie the derivative) exists as well?

Isn't this, well, obvious? Otherwise you could restrict the domain of otherwise differentiable functions and make the end-points of those restricted domains be mere left/right differentiable.

Nevertheless, I'm confused since I'm seeing questions on this site (as well comments on a previously deleted question) which suggest otherwise. Namely, when considering differentiable functions $f:[a,b]  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ people refer to the "right differentiability" of $f$ at $a$ (or left differentiability at $b$) rather than the simply, the differentiability.

Comment: Mathematical terminology is not always perfectly consistent. Sounds like you have the facts straight and you're just confused about the words people use to express those facts. Try not to worry about that.

Comment: I had a teacher once tell me endpoints are non-differentiable, or at least I seem to think so (I may be wrong). But this seems like one of those things where the meaning should be evident from context, though most folks I suspect would say to only look at the one-sided derivative for an endpoint and call that "the" derivative. This is probably one of many things where people will usually be able to figure out which convention you're using, and likewise you shouldn't have too much trouble figuring out what others mean.

Comment: I am unfortunately the guilty party who made the confusing comment. The truth is, either convention is fine in my opinion. You can call a function $f$ on $[a,b]$ *differentiable* or *right-differentiable* at $a$ with no change in meaning. I pointed out that $h \to 0^{-}$ at the right endpoint merely because this is an easy thing to forget when you write $h \to 0$. Writing $h \to 0^{-}$ means that, as one reads the formula, one doesn't need to think about the possible values of $h$. This was less obvious than, say, for $x \to b^{-}$ when $x \in (a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

As David C. Ullrich pointed out, it is in principle just a matter of how you name things. There is not always concensus between mathematicians about the technical details of a definition.

However, in this case I'd like to point out something that perhaps wasn't obvious to you already. If a function $f: ]a, b[ \to \mathbb{R}$ is right- and left-continuous at a point in its domain, it is automatically continuous at this point. This is *not* the case for differentiability. The function $f : ]-1, 1[ \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \lvert x \rvert$ is a classical example of a function that is left- and right-differentiable (and continuous) at $x=0$, but not differentiable.

Several important theorems about differentiable functions no longer hold when the condition 'diffentiability' if weakened to 'right- and left-differentiability'. Examples are:

- If a function $f: ]a, b[ \to \mathbb{R}$ reaches a local extremum in a point $c \in ]a, b[$, $f'(c) = 0$ ($c$ is a stationary point)
- The [Inverse Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem)

On the other hand, most theorems about continuity continue to hold (in some form) when there is instead only right-(left-)continuity at a boundary point of the domain. Perhaps this motivates why some authors simply put 'continuous' instead of right-(left-)continuous.

If you're a mathematics student, you might one day study topology, in which you'll see that continuity is, in fact, a much more general property than just one of real functions, but I'll let you look up the details yourself if you're interested.

Let me know if you still have any doubts.